# SQL CE deployment

Tags: deployment, sql-server-ce

I have a small windows app and am trying to use SQL CE for the local datastore.  I have had a couple of problems deploying it. I am using ClickOnce deployment.

First question:
In the `Publish properties -> Application Files` I have it set to Data File(Auto), Required, Include. However, it doesn't seem to be included?  When I navigate to the location that Click Once installs to its not there?

Second:
Click once creates a new directory in the `User\Local\Apps` directory, with the app files and SDF file in when I update the app and release a new version I don't want to start with a new database. All the data in the existing database will be lost? The just doesn't seem to make sense?

What is the procedure around this?